# Make zip/postal code field required in 'Estimate Shipping and Tax' section - Shopping Cart page

Tags: shipping, forms

Referring to the  'Estimate Shipping and Tax' section on Shopping Cart page - Magento EE 1.12.0.0, by default the 'Country', 'State/Province' and 'Zip/Postal Code' are not required.

[image]

This block is in the following template
frontend\enterprise\default\template\checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

As in the code snippet below, the 'required' (CSS) class is added only if $this->isZipCodeRequired() is set to true.

```
    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>>
<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
```

My question is: where is Magento checking for these values and can they be set in Magento Admin?

**Note** that the field "Postal Code is Optional for the following countries" in Magento Admin may not be an answer for this as, the above code snippet doesn't depend on the country.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make it required no matter what, just hard-code it in the template. It should be on the input, not just the label.

```
<label for="postcode" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
   <div class="input-box">
      <input class="input-text validate-postcode required-entry" type="text" id="postcode" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />
   </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to hard-code it in the template. My question is: where is Magento checking for these values and can they be set in Magento Admin? In other words, how is this method returning a true or false? $this->isZipCodeRequired()

Comment: Ah. Stepping backwards, 'function isZipCodeRequired' is in core/Mage/Checkout/BlockCart/Shipping.php. It goes through each carrier to find out if the zip code is required for that EstimateCountryId. From there, there's two functions. code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php has the same function, but it only returns false. The other is in code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract.php, which checks to see if ZipCodeOptional (return !Mage::helper('directory')->isZipCodeOptional($countryId);)

Comment: isZipCodeOptional is found in code/core/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php, which checks to see if the countrycode is in CountriesWithOptionalZip. Which pulls from the Magento admin. ($this->_optionalZipCountries = preg_split('/\,/', Mage::getStoreConfig(self::OPTIONAL_ZIP_COUNTRIES_CONFIG_PATH), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); )

Answer (score -2):

Log in to the admin and navigate to "System >> Configuration", under the General heading click "General". All the options are there.